# Android Kotlin. Troubles with databinding to recyclerview using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm trying to learn how to implement databinding in an Android app. I have a small app I'm working with to learn this. And while I have databinding working for part of the app. I have hit a hiccup when trying to implement a recyclerview. I just cannot seem to get it. Been banging away at it for two or three days, and getting frustrated. Thought I'd ask you guys.

The app is super simple at this point.

The part i'm stuck on is accessing my recyclerview from an .xml layout from my MainFragment.kt

At first I was trying to use binding, but got frustrated and went back to just trying to use findViewById, but that is giving me issue too. I am beginning to think, I don't have as firm a grasp on databinding as I thought I did.

This is from the fragment that holds the recyclerView:

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/job_recyclerView"/>
```

I have another small layout file that is using Cardview to show each individual item in the recyclerview

A super simple Model:

**JobData.kt**

```
data class JobData(val companyName: String, val location: String)
```

An Adapter:

**JobAdapter.kt**

```
class CustomAdapter(val userList: ArrayList<JobData>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

//Returning view for each item in the list
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.job_item_layout, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

//Binding the data on the list
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindItems(userList[position])
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return userList.size
}

//Class holds the job list view
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun bindItems(job: JobData) {
        val textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_company_name) as TextView
        val textViewAddress  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Location) as TextView
        textViewName.text = job.companyName
        textViewAddress.text = job.location
    }
}
}
```

And then the code in my MainFragment to handle it all, which it is not doing. I've tried everything, it was getting ugly. As you can see below. Binding is in place and working for my FloatingActionButton. But I for some reason cannot figure out how to access that recylerview. At the point the code is at below, I thought I'd just accessing using findViewById, but that is not working either.

**MainFragment.kt**
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val binding: FragmentMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater, R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)

    //Setting onClickListener for FAB(floating action button) using Navigation
    binding.createNewJobFAB.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
        v.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_createNewJobFragment)
    }

    //getting recyclerview from xml
    val recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.job_recyclerView) as RecyclerView

    //adding a layoutmanager
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)


    //Arraylist to store jobs using the data class JobData
    val jobs = ArrayList<JobData>()

    //add dummy data to list
    jobs.add(JobData("A Company", "Town A"))
    jobs.add(JobData("B Company", "Town B"))
    jobs.add(JobData("C Company", "Town C"))
    jobs.add(JobData("D Company", "Town D"))

    //creating adapter
    val adapter = CustomAdapter(jobs)

    //add adapter to recyclerView
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    return binding.root
}
}
```

The above fails to compile for two reasons:

1. findViewById shows as an "Unresolved Reference".
2. When adding the layoutManager, "this" shows as a "Type Mismatch"

Which I believe is due to the fact that Fragments do not have a context. Or so, I think anyway. But I don't know to resolve that? Maybe override some other method, but I can't seem to figure out which or how?

Oh and MainActivity looks like:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

//private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    @Suppress("UNUSED_VARIABLE")
    val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
}

//Ensures back button works as it should
override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragment).navigateUp()
}
```

Which is pointing to Nav_Graph for Android Navigation (part of JetPack). This bit is fine and working.

Adding gradle files to show that my dependencies were set correctly as suggested below.

**app/gradle**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
...
}

kapt {
generateStubs = true
correctErrorTypes = true
}

dependencies {
...
kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$gradle_version"

...
}
```

Comment: To make `findViewById()` and `LinearLayout` constructor work use [`Fragment#getContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getContext()). To solve problem with databinding, ensure please, that you have `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in `app/build.gradle` and `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:version"` in dependencies section of `app/build.gradle`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to show or mention my dependencies. Those are all set. I will edit main post to show that info. I will looki n into using Fragment#getContext() if I cannot get binding to work.

Comment: Have you already solved that problem?

Comment: No still working on it.

Comment: What is valuf of `$gradle_version`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to answer this for you.    $gradle_version allows me to only need to update version numbers in one place in my project level build.gradle file.

buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.3.10' }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encase your xml in `<layout>..<layout/>`

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentXXXBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = FragmentXXXBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return binding.root
    }
```

Then you can call recyclerview by `binding.jobRecyclerview`

try to set all the click listeners etc on `onViewCreated` rather than `onCreateView` of fragment

Comment: Your example is how i'd like to do this. And is one of the ways I tried the other day. But for reason I cannot figure out just yet, it does not work. 

I have my .xml incased in <layout>..<layout/> and have just added the lateinit to FragmentMainBinding. 

But calling binding.job_recyclerView is where it fails.

job_recyclerView remains as unresolved? This is where I am getting confused on binding.

Comment: binding.jobRecyclerview it should be, does it not auto fill? I'd so a clean/rebuild project if it's not autofilling

Comment: Agreed. I have cleaned/rebuilt project and even restarted Android Studio. It does not like it.

Comment: Can you please edit and post all xml, i've got a feeling it'll be something silly like a name wrong aha

Comment: Sorry, sorry. I fat fingered it. It is now seeing binding.jobRecyclerView.

Comment: This is exactly it. Thank you for the help. Everyone actually. I marked this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong way to findViewById from Fragment(it is good technique for Activity):

```
val recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.job_recyclerView) as RecyclerView
```

First, fragment's layout have to be return by onCreateView() method.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
}
```

I personally like do all fragment's business logic inside onViewCreated()

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    //Now, we can use views by kotlinx
    //val recyclerView = job_recyclerView
    //Or old-fashioned way
    val recyclerView = getView()!!.findViewById(R.id.job_recyclerView) as RecyclerView
}
```

RecylerView can be accessed from fragment's layout by having root view like: `getView()!!.findViewById` or by kotlinx inside onViewCreated(): `job_recyclerView`

Comment: Sorry, your formatting is confusing to me? It seems like your suggesting using both 'onCreateView' and 'onViewCreated', or am I reading this wrong?

Comment: Agree with koliczyna, `onViewCreated()` should handle the business logic, not `oncreateView()`, this should just be for inflating the layout

Comment: @CB Midkiff You are correct, I suggest to use both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  so first of all you are getting error on `findViewById` because your fragment is unaware about the view that contains `recyclerView`

What you should do is,  take an instance of view that you are inflating for this fragment (declare view as a global variable, replace your inflater line with this).

```
var rootView

// Inside onCreateView
var rootView = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false)
```

Now replace, `findViewById()` with `rootView.findViewById()`

And the other error is because the fragment does not have any context of it's own so replace `this` with `activity!!`

By writing `activity!!` you are calling `getActicity()` method which returns context of parent activity.

Comment: I followed your suggestions and it did take care of the compiler errors, and the app now runs. The RecyclerView does not populate as it should. I does not show up at all. I think it is how that inflater is called. But I only had a little bit of time to work on it. I've been at the immigration offices all day dealing with Visa issues. Im going to work on it more this afternoon and tonight.